# Word Cloud making error in Python: string indices must be integers

Tags: python, word-cloud

I'm trying to make a Word Cloud out of a txt file with this code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
from IPython.display import Image as im

file = open("T.txt", encoding='utf-8')
FR = file.read()


raw_file = []

for line in FR:
    raw_file.append(line['text'])

words = raw_file.split(" ")
words = [w for w in words if len(w) > 2]  
words = [w.lower() for w in words]
words = [w for w in words if w not in STOPWORDS]


word_list = (words)
word_counter = {}
for word in word_list:
     if word in word_counter:
         word_counter[word] += 1
     else:
         word_counter[word] = 1

popular_words = sorted(word_counter, key = word_counter.get, reverse = True)

topp = popular_words

topp.remove('https')


mask = np.array(Image.open('/Users/x/Downloads/B.png'))

wc = WordCloud(background_color="black", max_words=2000, mask=mask)
clean_string = ','.join(topp)
wc.generate(clean_string)



plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.title("Title", size=40)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```

As in the title, it gives me Error: string indices must be integers on raw_file.append(line['text']).
I tried a few different methods to make it work but it didn't, so I'm asking here for help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

replace

```
raw_file.append(line['text'])
```

with

```
raw_file.append(line)
```

when you do `line['text']` you're trying to take the element 'text' from the object `line`, but line is a string, and `'text'` is not a valid index for a string type.

actually what you want would normally be

```
with open('T.txt') as f:
    raw_file = f.readlines()
```

because it does what you seem to be trying to do and then closes the file handler at the end rather than leaving it open (as you are currently doing).

You're then going to have some trouble because you're trying to treat a list of lines as a string, which it isn't. I suggest you try writing this line by line and working out what you actually want to do. Stackoverflow will eventually write this whole code for you, but that's not really helping you learn anything.

Answer (score 0):

`line` from `file.read()` reads a single char. You want to use `file.readlines()` and iterate over that. 
I don't know why you are trying to use line as a dictionary `line['text']`.
This is what throws the error, since you cant access the `text` key.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a few unnecessary things, without which you can make your code a bit simpler. The actual problem is how you are indexing `line['text']`, but there is also a problem with how you then turn `raw_file` into `words`.

You don't actually need `FR = file.read()` (of `file.readlines()`). `for line in file:` does the same thing for you.

Appending the lines then to `raw_file` and then using `.split(" ")` on that, will try to split on a list of lines, giving you your next error. You can just split the line directly and add that to your list of `words`.

You also don't need to change `words` into `word_list` or `popular_words` into `topp`. IMHO this only just creates more variables and makes the code less readable.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
from IPython.display import Image as im

file = open("T.txt", encoding='utf-8')

words = []

for line in file:
    words += line.split()

words = [w for w in words if len(w) > 2]  
words = [w.lower() for w in words]
words = [w for w in words if w not in STOPWORDS]

word_counter = {}
for word in words:
     if word in word_counter:
         word_counter[word] += 1
     else:
         word_counter[word] = 1

popular_words = sorted(word_counter, key = word_counter.get, reverse = True)

popular_words.remove('https')

mask = np.array(Image.open('/Users/x/Downloads/B.png'))

wc = WordCloud(background_color="black", max_words=2000, mask=mask)
clean_string = ','.join(popular_words)
wc.generate(clean_string)

plt.imshow(wc, interpolation='bilinear')
plt.title("Title", size=40)
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
```